# Sum numbers each 80 lines one line awk

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, awk

I have a very large text file that's a vector of numbers, and I would like to add 80 lines together, print the result in a new file, then take the second 81-160 lines, add them up and print the result in the next line of the new file, and so on, until the end of file.

NOte that the number of lines is not necessarily multiple of 80 so for the last line I'd have to add the remaining lines.

Is it possible to do this fast and in one line using awk, or similar programming language?

Thanks.

Note2: the file looks like this:

```
3.456
3.4
6.788
9.342
... etc ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest awk solution I can come up with is this (47 chars if golfed):

```
awk '{ s += $1 } NR % c == 0 { print s; s=0 } END { if(NR % c) print s }' c=80
```

`s` accumulates the sum. Every 80 lines the sum is printed and `s` is reset. The `END` clause prints the final sum if `NR % 80 != 0`.

Comment: I'd always use "-v c=80" unless you have a specific reason not to since setting a variable as above has the caveat that the variable's value is then not available in the BEGIN section, but otherwise this is THE correct solution in terms of idiomatic awk.

Answer (score 4):

another awk one-liner:

```
awk '{s+=$0;if( NR%80==0){print s-r;r=s}}END{if(s!=r)print s-r}' file
```

test with **seq 21** and every **5** line:

```
kent$  seq 21|awk '{s+=$0;if(NR%5==0){print s-r;r=s}}END{if(s!=r)print s-r}' 
15
40
65
90
21
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN {c=0; tot=0};
    {
        tot=tot+$1;
        c++;
        if (c==80) {
            print tot;
            c=0
            tot=0
        }
    };
    END {print tot}'
```

(Tested and it works)

Comment: @Kent fixed =) I just tried with (c==5) and got the same output as you.

Comment: Lots of things will "work" without using the idiomatic syntax for a language. The above re-initializes variables that are automatically init-ed already, adds trailing null-statements to the end of several lines courtesy of useless semi-colons, uses a manual variable c when the builtin NR works just fine, doesn't use the builtin condition/action syntax but instead hand-codes the condition within the action section, etc. It's C syntax written in an awk script. It would also produce a trailing 0 if there was a multiple of 80 input lines. See the answer by @thor.

Comment: @EdMorton hey Ed, I really appreciate you taking the time to explain these idioms to me; this is actually very helpful! =)

Comment: @sampson-chen - no problem and sorry, on re-reading it my first post sounded pretty negative, I was in a hurry and didn't really think about the tone when I was typing it.

Comment: @EdMorton oh no, not at all - I love opportunities to learn something new!

Answer (score 1):

clean output verion:

```
 awk '{
    if ( NR%80 ){tot+=$0} 
    else{tot+=$0;print tot; tot=0}
   }
   END {if (NR%80 !=0 ) print tot}
 ' file > sumFile
```

Note that you can change the 80 to any value.

Debugging version

```
awk '{
   if ( NR%80 ){
       print "line="$0;tot+=$0} 
   else{
       print "2line="$0;
       tot+=$0;
       print "tot="tot; 
       tot=0
     }
   }
  END {
      if (NR%80!=0) print "2tot="tot
  }' file
```

IHTH.

Comment: Should `if (tot < 0)` be `if (tot != 0)`?  And even that's vulnerable to negative and positive numbers summing to zero.  If you use `if (NR%80 != 0)`, then you'd have an accurate condition, I believe.

Comment: @kent: tot<0 will only have a value when an uneven number of records for the condtion NR%30 is meet. JL has 2 better solutions. (I tested it lightly with 2 values, one that was an even divisor of the NR while the other value meant that the else condition didn't get fired. Both tests passed my quick valiation using the dugging setup. Jonathan L. you're right either of your tests are better. Changing my solution. Thanks and good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open( my $fh,  '<', 'nums.txt' ) or die $!;
open( my $out, '>', 'res.txt' )  or die $!;

my $sum        = 0;
my $line_count = 1;

while (<$fh>) {
    $line_count++;
    chomp;
    $sum += $_;
    if ( $line_count == 80 or eof($fh) ) {
        print $out "$sum\n";
        $line_count = 0;
        $sum        = 0;
    }
}

close($fh);
close($out);
```

The file names are up to you as well.  It will print the sum of the first 80 lines and then the next successively followed by a newline.